# Get data from multiple 'mat-checkbox' in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to fill an array with selected checkboxes but also remove the entrys when I uncheck the checkbox. But I'm struggling with the implementation in the .ts-class, can you help me?

component.html

```
  <div class="propertys" fxFlex="column">
     <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let p of properties" (click)="setProperties(p)">{{p.name}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

Comment: Define multi check boxes with an id or an set and ngModel variable to it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SelectionModel.

```
<div class="propertys" fxFlex="column">
  <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let p of properties" 
  [checked]="selectedItens.isSelected(p)" 
  (click)="setProperties(p, $event)">
    {{p.name}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

ts:

```
selectedItems = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

setProperties(p: any, event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  selectedItems.toggle(p);
}

getItems(): any[] {
  return this.selectedItems.selected;
}
```

You may have some problems if you are using objects as the value and you reload it from an API (then i recommend you using the SelectionModel with the ID), but if your checkboxes are static, this should work.